# JSON.parse string with unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

Parsing this string I get an unexpected token error, what is the unexpected token?

```
JSON.parse("​[{"attr1":079455,"Attr2": 3},{"Attr1":847987​​,"Attr2": 3}]​​​");
```

I keep looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) at the documentation but I'm just not seeing what's wrong with this string? I've tried all sorts of stringifying and replacing double quotes with single ect.

Comment: `079455` --- this is not a valid number as per the JSON standard. Where did you get it from?

Comment: It's just a sample of some data I get from the backend, I'm thinking something is formatted incorrectly

Comment: Well, if you're using some library to generate JSON - it has a bug. If you generate it manually, then you should not do that and use some proper implementation instead.

Answer (score 0):

JSON format does not allow leading zeroes on numbers, except for the special case of `0` or floating point numbers that begin with `0.`. See the diagram that shows the format of numbers at http://www.json.org/.

So the number `079455` is not valid JSON.

You should fix the program that's generating the JSON in the first place. It should use a library function to produce JSON, instead of formatting it by hand.

If you can't, you could use the following clumsy Javascript to remove the extraneous zeroes:

```
json_str = json_str.replace(/":0+/, '":');
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as incorrect number formats, you are not correctly wrapping your String. If you want to include `"` characters inside your string, you should wrap it with `'`:

`JSON.parse('[{"attr1":79455,"Attr2": 3},{"Attr1":847987,"Attr2": 3}]');`